# Numpy select index randomly

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that is like this

```py
arr = np.random.randint(2, size=(32, 4, 19))
```

and I want to output a random index for `arr` that is equal to 1 in respect to `axis=2`. So I want to return an array that is of shape `(32, 4, 1)` consisting of a random index that is 1. For example, say the first few rows of the array looks like this

```py
array([[[0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0]],
        ...
       [[0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1]]])
```

I want to get something like

```py
array([[[1],[17],[16],[5]], 
       [[3], ...
        ....
       [[7],[4],[7],[11]]])
```

since `arr[0,0,1] == 1` and `arr[0,1,17] == 1` etc.
Can someone please help me

Comment: What do you mean by "random index"? Your terminology would imply that the index is itself random, but your example appears deterministic. Do you mean you are looking to construct an array `b` of all the indices of the array `arr` that have value `1`?

Comment: @danmohad Sorry if the question seems vague. I gave the example just for clarification but it seemed to backfire.  The example is just one of many samples that can occur. what I want is to get a random index for each row which have the value `1`, so again using the example above, the first value in the result could be anything varying from 1, 17, 18 or anything between that has the value `1`

Comment: Let's consider a simpler 2D case. `arr` of size N x M is initialized randomly to `0`s and `1`s. You want to construct a vector `b` of size N x 1 where each element `b[i]` is a column index `j` for `arr`, where `arr[i, j]` has value `1`. However, there may be more than one `j` for which `arr[i, j]` has value `1`, or there may be none at all. What should be done in these cases?

Comment: @danmohad For my application we can assume that every column has at least 1 index `j` that has the value `1`. If there are more than one `j`, then a random `j` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have at least one 1 per vector on axis 2, you can multiply each item by a random value and get the `argmax`, then reshape to add an extra dimension:

```
np.argmax(arr*np.random.random(size=arr.shape), axis=2)[...,None]
```

Example output:

```
[[[ 6], [ 7], [ 9], [ 5]],
 [[10], [15], [13], [16]],
 [[ 1], [ 9], [ 3], [16]],
 [[ 0], [18], [14], [ 0]],
 [[10], [14], [ 1], [11]],
...
]
```

*NB. If the last dimension (19) is extremely large, you might have a bias towards lower indices in case twice the same random value is generated (`argmax` will pick the first max), but this is extremely unlikely and will still give a correct result.*